# Unable to get image to render in Jupyter markdown cell

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to add an image to a markdown cell in my notebook. Previously, I'd been using:

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename='/Users/nzhang/Desktop/DS/Python/images/imagename.jpeg', width=400, height=400)
```

That worked fine in code cells. However, I want to add an image to a markdown cell like this:

`![title](img//Users/nzhang/Desktop/DS/Python/images/imagename.jpeg)`

but I'm getting a thumbnail of a broken image in its place.

Comment: Try to remove img/ from the path

Comment: why do you add `img/` to path ?

Comment: I tried removing `img/` but I'm getting the same broken thumbnail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<img src="imagename.jpeg">
```

This works great in markdown cells. Please let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Anytime! @nzhang

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: @Galen, try wrapping the img tag in a div. That worked for me.

Comment: @ArthurvanAcker Thank you for sharing that. Next time I will try wrapping in a `div`.